# Synchronously Send and Receive Bluetooth Data using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-bluetooth

This has been the method so far to send and receive on bluetooth using Java with threading. But how do we do this using Kotlin's latest Coroutines? Alot of this old Java cold no longer translates to Kotlin 1.4+ either in terms of how to do threading. I read Kotlin is now using Coroutines instead of threads like before.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66")


    public void pairDevice(View v) {

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            Object[] devices = pairedDevices.toArray();
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) devices[0]

            ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(device,MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            connect.start();

        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run(){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            mmSocket = tmp;

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                }
            }

            //will talk about this in the 3rd video
            connected(mmSocket);
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket) {

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {    
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    final String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);    
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            view_data.setText(incomingMessage);
                        }
                    });


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

    }

    public void SendMessage(View v) {
        byte[] bytes = send_data.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
        mConnectedThread.write(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        send_data =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        view_data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null && !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new
                    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    public void Start_Server(View view) {
        AcceptThread accept = new AcceptThread();
        accept.start();
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread(){
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null ;
                try{
                tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("appname", MY_UUID_INSECURE);

            }catch (IOException e){
}
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try{
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
    
            }catch (IOException e){
            }

            //talk about this is in the 3rd
            if(socket != null){
                connected(socket);
            }

        }

    }
```